# Vue JS - Issue adding multiple components

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to Vue JS and I've read several different articles online and I can't figure out how to display my component. I'm using Laravel 5.5.

I have a login view page with the following:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="login-box">
        <login-form></login-form>
    </div><!-- /.login-box -->
</div>
```

I created a `Login.vue` page at `/components/Auth/Login.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div class="login-box-body">
        <p class="login-box-msg"> Sign in to start your session. </p>
        <form action="{{ url('/login') }}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username"/>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <a href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}"> Forgot Password? </a><br>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

I've registered it in the `app.js` file:

```
require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
Vue.component('login-form', require('./components/Auth/Login.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

});
```

I'm getting the error, `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <login-form> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. (found in root instance)`.

I've registered it in `app.js` as seen above and if I use `<example></example>` it appears correctly.

I changed the `Example.vue` to the template file and it didn't update -it's still showing the old template. How can I get this to appear?

Comment: try to provide a name for your login component as it says in the error text. to do this add `name: 'login-form',` in the exported object at Login.vue

Comment: @oniondomes like this? `export default {
        name:'login-form',
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }` - tried that and still getting the same error.

Comment: I just trying to help by gues, but try to get rid of these inline `require`s. `const Login = require('./components/Auth/Login.vue');` right after the bootstrap line. If it still doesn't work, examine its value

Comment: Can you update your question and include code from `bootstrap.js` file in `resources/assets/js` folder?

Comment: @NikolaGavric its the default laravel setup...https://github.com/laravel/laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recall struggling with the same issue a few weeks back.

In short form, the fix is to *not do it like that*.

Instead, you want to register each component explicitly as such:

```
require('./bootstrap');

const Example =  require('./components/Example.vue');
const Login = require('./components/Auth/Login.vue');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { Example, Login }
});
```

The above has to be done not only for the `Vue` but for all nested components as well.

Comment: While this might fix the issue, here is the reference registering global and local components: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-Components

Comment: Hmm, still having some issues. I'm trying to use the tag, `<login-form>` and with Laravel it seems like it's not even picking up this vue file in `resources/js/app.js` do I need to move this to `public/js/..etc`? This is the base install of Laravel - nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is what I thought it is, but I thought that line was in `bootstrap.js` thats why I wanted to see that file, anyhow, you will notice how you never imported the `Vue` inside of your `app.js` and from the `laravel` starter project, that line is inside `app.js` not `bootstrap.js` and just by looking at your `app.js` I saw you are missing

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
```

So my guess is by adding this line just under `require('./bootstrap.js'); your app will register both`Vue` components